# How to use recursive function in laravel to show multiple categories

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make an e-commerce mega menu. I did everything and its working but there is a problem.

My codes show this :

[My code result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npkoT.png)

As you see Laptop Accessories category actually Laptop's subcategory but looks like an another Computer's subcategory. This is my categorytree.blade.php

```
@foreach($children as $subcategory)
@if(count($subcategory->children))
    <li class="ltn__category-submenu-title ltn__category-menu-drop"><a  href="#">{{$subcategory->name}}</a>

        <ul class="ltn__category-submenu-children">
            @include('home.categorytree', ['children'=> $subcategory->children])
        </ul>
    </li>

@else

    <li class="ltn__category-submenu-title ltn__category-menu-drop" ><a  href="#">{{$subcategory->name}}</a>
@endif @endforeach
```

How can i show that ul class inside normal link and other subcategroies bold link?

Comment: Have you inspect its code Like what tags it is using in html

Comment: Might be its subcategory have same CSS. because it is at least printing it under LAPTOP not under desktop

Comment: working in sub li. This is the problem i cannot call this ul inside with different css

Comment: No in browser inspect element and see is UL exists